# Is it possible to sync a folder from Dropbox to iBook in iPad?

Tags: ipad, dropbox, ibook

I want to copy an folder which may contain lots of folders from Dropbox to iBook, and keep the folder hierarchy correct. I used to use GoodReader and works fine, but it crashes a lot under iOS 7.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't possible. iBooks just isn't intended to support it. You can create "collections" which are essentially folders, but you can only import one PDF/ePub at time and then you'll need to manually sort them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible since iBooks does not support bulk importing of content from other applications on an iOS device. The three ways to add books to iBooks are:

- Purchase from the iBooks store and download
- Sync books through iTunes
- Send a single book (not several) from another application on the iOS device with the **Open In...iBooks** option

Also, iBooks does not have the concept of folders and folder hierarchies. It does have **Collections**, but there is no way to map folders to **Collections** from iTunes or any other source.

Comment: I cannot include this as part of the answer, but keep an eye out when OS X Mavericks is released. It comes with a built-in iBooks app, and may probably provide the ability to add folders of books into iBooks and sync them to iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://chib.me/dropbooks/

It allows you to sync iBooks with any folder on your Mac. You could use it with Dropbox folder.